# AWS - EC2 unable to detect EBS drives

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, amazon-ebs

after an unexpected restart on a windows server 2021 r2 server, the server is unable to detect the EBS drives. i have attached about 4 drives but they are invisible/not detected in device manager/disk manager, i.e., only c drive is visible in the disk manager..refresh/rescan disk didnt help either.

Could someone advice on  how we can get back the disks.

Comment: Have you checked the Windows Event Logs?

Comment: yea..but i see no difference even with device manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest following the step here, update the PV driver, and this fixed the issue.

====

1. Create an AMI copy from the AWS console as a backup: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html
2. Uninstall the AWS PV Driver Version 7.2.0 via "Programs and Features.”
3. Reboot the machine when prompted by the uninstaller.
4. Download and install the AWS PV Driver Installer from: https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-windows-drivers/AWS+PV+7.2.0/MicrosoftSigned/Installer/AWSPVDriverPackager.exe
5. Reboot when prompted by the installer.
6. Download and run the following script: http://ec2-downloads-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Scripts/RemediateDriverIssue.zip, this will ensure that this issue is corrected ongoing.